# Unable to scroll through search results in App Store on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I’m using an iPhone 5s running iOS 12.2. I can't scroll in the App Store after entering a search term. The Search results load, but it just won't scroll down the list of results.

However, tapping on Featured, Categories, Top Charts or Updates, the scrolling works just fine. But tapping back on Search it just refuses to scroll.

What could be causing this? How do I resolve?